# how can i overcome this warning

Tags: php, email

Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\learn\mail2.php on line 9
failure email

```
my code is
```

`

```
$headers = 'From:<akhilgundu401@gmail.com>'."\r\n".
'Reply-To:akhilyagna1@gmail.com'."\r\n".'X-Mailer:PHP/'.PHPversion();

$res=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
if($res)
{
    echo 'email sent successfully';
   }
 else {   
echo 'failure email';
}
?>
```

Comment: the warning message already tells you what to do: `verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting` - since you apparently use windows, you probably don't have an smtp-server. so you have to setup one and configure php to use it.

Comment: smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

Comment: please don't put anything multiline in the comment fields because it gets utterly unreadable. edit your original post instead. and please: provide an explanation *what* it is supposed to be, we can't read minds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a mail server on your machine for the mail function to work. If you are on Windows  you can setup a [Pegasus](http://www.pmail.com/) mail server.

Other options include using a wrapper class such as SwiftMailer or PHPMailer and using them to connect to another SMTP server such as your GMail account.

OR Try This

In C:\xampp\php\php.ini find extension=php_openssl.dll and remove the semicolon from the beginning of that line to make SSL working for gmail for localhost.

in php.ini file find [mail function] and change

SMTP=smtp.gmail.com

smtp_port=587

sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com

sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

Now Open C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini. Replace all the existing code in sendmail.ini with following code

[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

smtp_port=587

error_logfile=error.log

debug_logfile=debug.log

auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com

auth_password=my-gmail-password

force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com

openssl is required for gmail mail server so you need to check if your php installation has openssl support  . to see this  use `phpinfo()` function  run this function on a blank php file n search for openssl  if it is there then in your code where you are using mail function write these lines before sending mail  `ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
 ini_set("smtp_port","465");` 
it will set up required ports n smtp and also
you have to activate IMAP in Google Mail first! inside google setting

Comment: Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. h185sm32671310pfe.35 - gsmtp in C:\xampp\htdocs\learn\mail2.php on line 9
failure email

Comment: And if i run the code then it is autometicely debugging by itself

Comment: First, make sure you PHP installation has SSL support (look for an "openssl" section in the output from phpinfo()).

You can set the following settings in your PHP.ini:


ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","465");

Comment: please can u explan it detail

Comment: <?php
$to = 'akhilyagna1@gmail.com';
$subject = 'this is my first php mail';
$message = 'iam akhil from yagna tech , thanks';

$headers = 'From:<akhilgundu401@gmail.com>'."\r\n".
'Reply-To:akhilyagna1@gmail.com'."\r\n".'X-Mailer:PHP/'.PHPversion();

$res=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
if($res)
{
    echo 'email sent successfully';
   }
 else {   
echo 'failure email';
}
?>

Comment: write ini_set line before using mail function